Fetch string only until specific word on ruby

I am building a scraper/parsing method, but the website I am using (https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/search?q=banana)to get the value from have many different informations using the same classes (they have no id, and are in the very same tag). In my case, I just need the preparation time, but it gives me other stuff i don't need.
HTML fragment
<article class="card text-align-left card--horizontal card--inline card--with-borders" data-item-id="233531" data-item-name="Banana bread" data-variant="horizontal" data-index="1" data-component="Card" data-item-type="recipe" data-subscription-experience="default">
  <div class="card__section card__media">
    <div class="d-block p-relative">
      <div class="p-absolute card__media-buttons pa-xs"></div>
    </div>
    <a class="link d-block p-relative card__image-container" href="/recipes/brilliant-banana-loaf" data-component="Link" aria-label="View Banana bread">
      <div class="card__overlay-icon p-absolute d-grid justify-content-center align-content-center card__overlay-icon--horizontal"><i class="icon" style="width:24px;min-width:24px;height:24px;min-height:24px;animation-duration:1000ms"><svg class="icon__svg" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" style="color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);fill:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"><use xlink:href="/static/icons/base/sprite-maps/media-f9e9817ead29e7dce81069945ff5bbe8.svg#play"></use></svg></i></div>
      <div
      class="image chromatic-ignore card__img image--fluid image--scaled-up">
        <div class="image__container">
          <picture class="image__picture" width="93" height="84.51190476190476">
            <source type="image/webp" sizes="93px" srcset="https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/06/recipe-image-legacy-id-1273522_8-a6b9246.jpg?quality=90&amp;webp=true&amp;resize=93,85 93w,https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/06/recipe-image-legacy-id-1273522_8-a6b9246.jpg?quality=90&amp;webp=true&amp;resize=186,169 186w,https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/06/recipe-image-legacy-id-1273522_8-a6b9246.jpg?quality=90&amp;webp=true&amp;resize=279,254 279w,https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/06/recipe-image-legacy-id-1273522_8-a6b9246.jpg?quality=90&amp;webp=true&amp;resize=372,338 372w">
            <source sizes="93px" srcset="https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/06/recipe-image-legacy-id-1273522_8-a6b9246.jpg?quality=90&amp;resize=93,85 93w,https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/06/recipe-image-legacy-id-1273522_8-a6b9246.jpg?quality=90&amp;resize=186,169 186w,https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/06/recipe-image-legacy-id-1273522_8-a6b9246.jpg?quality=90&amp;resize=279,254 279w,https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/06/recipe-image-legacy-id-1273522_8-a6b9246.jpg?quality=90&amp;resize=372,338 372w"><img class="image__img" src="https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/06/recipe-image-legacy-id-1273522_8-a6b9246.jpg?quality=90&amp;resize=93,85" alt="Sliced banana bread topped with drizzle and banana chips on a serving plate"
            data-item-name="Sliced banana bread topped with drizzle and banana chips on a serving plate" title="Banana bread" style="aspect-ratio:1 / 0.9087301587301587;object-fit:cover" loading="lazy" width="93" height="84.51190476190476"></picture>
        </div>
  </div>
  </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card__section card__content"><a class="link d-block" href="/recipes/brilliant-banana-loaf" data-component="Link"><h2 class="heading-4" style="color:inherit">Banana bread</h2></a>
    <div class="card__rating rating">
      <div class="rating__values rating__values--no-rate" aria-label="rating">
        <div class="rating__stars d-flex"><i class="rating__icon d-inline-flex icon" style="width:15px;min-width:15px;height:15px;min-height:15px;animation-duration:1000ms"><svg class="icon__svg" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" style="color:inherit;fill:inherit"><use xlink:href="/static/icons/base/sprite-maps/stars-f9e9817ead29e7dce81069945ff5bbe8.svg#star-fill"></use></svg></i>
          <i
          class="rating__icon d-inline-flex icon" style="width:15px;min-width:15px;height:15px;min-height:15px;animation-duration:1000ms">
            <svg class="icon__svg" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" style="color:inherit;fill:inherit">
              <use xlink:href="/static/icons/base/sprite-maps/stars-f9e9817ead29e7dce81069945ff5bbe8.svg#star-fill"></use>
            </svg>
            </i><i class="rating__icon d-inline-flex icon" style="width:15px;min-width:15px;height:15px;min-height:15px;animation-duration:1000ms"><svg class="icon__svg" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" style="color:inherit;fill:inherit"><use xlink:href="/static/icons/base/sprite-maps/stars-f9e9817ead29e7dce81069945ff5bbe8.svg#star-fill"></use></svg></i>
            <i
            class="rating__icon d-inline-flex icon" style="width:15px;min-width:15px;height:15px;min-height:15px;animation-duration:1000ms">
              <svg class="icon__svg" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" style="color:inherit;fill:inherit">
                <use xlink:href="/static/icons/base/sprite-maps/stars-f9e9817ead29e7dce81069945ff5bbe8.svg#star-fill"></use>
              </svg>
              </i><i class="rating__icon d-inline-flex icon" style="width:15px;min-width:15px;height:15px;min-height:15px;animation-duration:1000ms"><svg class="icon__svg" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" style="color:inherit;fill:inherit"><use xlink:href="/static/icons/base/sprite-maps/stars-f9e9817ead29e7dce81069945ff5bbe8.svg#star-fill"></use></svg></i></div>
        <span
        class="sr-only">A star rating of 4.5 out of 5.</span><span class="rating__count-text body-copy-small">1883 ratings</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card__section card__footer">
    <ul style="height:22px" class="terms-icons-list d-flex card__footer-item terms-icons-list--single-row list list--horizontal">
      <li class="d-flex pb-xs pr-md list-item">
        <div class="icon-stack mr-xxs icon-stack--vertical-align" style="height:22px;width:22px">
          <div class="icon-stack__icon" style="z-index:2"><i class="card__term-icon icon" style="width:22px;min-width:22px;height:22px;min-height:22px;animation-duration:1000ms"><svg class="icon__svg" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" style="color:inherit;fill:inherit"><use xlink:href="/static/icons/base/sprite-maps/core-f9e9817ead29e7dce81069945ff5bbe8.svg#clock-hands"></use></svg></i></div>
          <div
          class="icon-stack__icon" style="z-index:1"><i class="card__term-icon-base icon" style="width:22px;min-width:22px;height:22px;min-height:22px;animation-duration:1000ms"><svg class="icon__svg" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" style="color:inherit;fill:inherit"><use xlink:href="/static/icons/base/sprite-maps/shapes-f9e9817ead29e7dce81069945ff5bbe8.svg#circle"></use></svg></i></div>
  </div><span class="terms-icons-list__text d-flex align-items-center" style="height:22px">1 hr 5 mins</span></li>
  <li class="d-flex pb-xs list-item">
    <div class="icon-stack mr-xxs icon-stack--vertical-align" style="height:22px;width:22px">
      <div class="icon-stack__icon" style="z-index:2"><i class="card__term-icon icon" style="width:14px;min-width:14px;height:14px;min-height:14px;animation-duration:1000ms"><svg class="icon__svg" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" style="color:inherit;fill:inherit"><use xlink:href="/static/icons/base/sprite-maps/food-f9e9817ead29e7dce81069945ff5bbe8.svg#chefs-hat"></use></svg></i></div>
      <div
      class="icon-stack__icon" style="z-index:1"><i class="card__term-icon-base icon" style="width:22px;min-width:22px;height:22px;min-height:22px;animation-duration:1000ms"><svg class="icon__svg" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" style="color:inherit;fill:inherit"><use xlink:href="/static/icons/base/sprite-maps/shapes-f9e9817ead29e7dce81069945ff5bbe8.svg#circle"></use></svg></i></div>
    </div><span class="terms-icons-list__text d-flex align-items-center" style="height:22px">Easy</span></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</article>

What I need: " 1 hr 5 mins" (the prep time could be only minutes, so i need everything before the 'mins', including it)
What I get: "1 hr 5 minsEasy" (also I can't say which word will come after "mins", could be "hard" for example)
this is where im stuck:
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require_relative "recipe"

class Scraper
  def initialize(ingredient)
    @ingredient = ingredient
  end

  def call
    html = URI.open("https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/search?q=#{@ingredient}").read
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html, nil, "utf-8")
    results = []
    doc.search("article.card.text-align-left.card--horizontal.card--inline.card--with-borders").first(1).each do |element|
      name = element.search("h2.heading-4").text.strip
      description = element.search(".region-clamper.line-clamper__content").text.strip
      prep_time = element.search(".terms-icons-list__text.d-flex.align-items-center").children.text.strip.split("Easy").first
     #to be continued...    
    end
    results
  end
end


Just a friendly heads up; You can only use the derived data for your own personal and non-commercial use. So if this isn't a courosity project to learn more about web scrapers you may be wasting time on a idea that could land you in court. https://www.immediate.co.uk/terms-and-conditions/

If you need string "1 hr 5 mins", just get it
results =
  doc.css("article.card.text-align-left.card--horizontal.card--inline.card--with-borders").map do |article|
    {
      # ... other keys
      prep_time: article.at(".card__section.card__footer ul li span").text,
      # ... other keys
    }
  end

Here css method returns collection of tags (node set) with given selector (article with given classes)
Mapping through this collection is parsing of every element. at method returns first element with given selector. Preparation time is located inside span of the first li of the ul
Of course you can parse that string to store only integer minutes
time_ary = article.at(".card__section.card__footer ul li span").text.scan(/\d+/)
prep_time = time_ary.pop.to_i + time_ary[0].to_i * 60

Here String#scan is used with regexp for integers
How it works. Remove last element with Array#pop and get first element by 0 index
time_ary = ["1", "20"]
prep_time = time_ary.pop.to_i + time_ary[0].to_i * 60 # => 80

time_ary = ["20"]
prep_time = time_ary.pop.to_i + time_ary[0].to_i * 60 # => 20

That's because [][0] returns nil and nil.to_i returns 0
